# Define the ember data model for nested rest url

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to do something that sounds simple but I can't find the solution.

My application needs to edit documents which contains pages.

Here is my model :

```js
MyApplication.Document = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    pages: DS.hasMany('page', {async: true})
});
MyApplication.Page = DS.Model.extend({
    document: DS.belongsTo('document', {async: true}),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    params: DS.attr(),
    objects: DS.attr()
});
```

And the routes :

```
MyApplication.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('document', {path: '/document/:document_id'});
});
MyApplication.Document = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('document', params.document_id);
    }
});
```

When I load the document 1, the application call `http://www.myserver.com/api/document/1`.

The problem is that when I want to find a page of the document, it calls

- `http://www.myserver.com/api/pages/ID`

instead of

- `http://www.myserver.com/api/document/1/pages/ID`

Theses nested URL are important in my application.

I found different things on the subject like adding `links` in the JSON response :

```js
{
    "document": {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Titre du document",
        "pages": ["1", "2", "3"],
        "links": {"pages" : "pages"}
},
```

But when I call for the pages, it requests `http://www.myserver.com/api/document/1/pages` without the id.

I also try specify the document when I ask for the page :

```js
this.store.find("page", 1, {document:1});
```

Can't find a complete documentation on this subject, so if someone can explain me what's wrong, I'll be happy.

Thank.

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: Also, have you entertained nested routes in your application but keeping the API flat -- IE exposing `http://www.myserver.com/api/documents/1` and `http://www.myserver.com/api/pages/1` instead of a nested API. Are you in control of the API?

Comment: It's important to get this nested structure in the API because I need to know the document to find the page. The api request on real document, not on a DB

Answer (score 3):

Depends : **EMBER DATA >= V1.0.0-BETA.9**

The way to handle nested routes is hidden under [release notes](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html#toc_better-support-for-nested-records)

1. Need to send back the links with response like this

   ```
   {
       "document": {
       "id": 1,
       "title": "Titre du document",
       "links": {"pages" : "/documents/1/pages"}
   }
   ```
2. You'll need to customize the `adapter:page`'s `buldUrl` method like

   ```
   MyApplication.PageAdapter = DS.RestAdapter.extend({
     // NOTE: this is just a simple example, but you might actually need more customization when necessary
     buildURL: function(type, id, snapshot) {
       return '/documents/' + snapshot.record.get('document.id') + '/pages/' + id;
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

[@code-jaff answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30458763/316700) adapted to Ember 2.1.0:

```
// app/adapters/page.js
import DS from './application'; // I suppose you have your adapter/application.js

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(type, id, snapshot) {
    return this.host + '/' + this.namespace + '/documents/' + snapshot.record.get('document.id') + '/pages/' + id;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely stems from the quotes that are surrounding the IDs in your JSON. If you modify your serializer so that there are no quotes for the the IDs both around the document ID and the pages IDs, you should get the behavior that you expect. Also, you need to modify the formatting of your links to point to the relative path:

The resulting JSON should look like:

```
{
    "document": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Titre du document",
        "pages": [1, 2, 3],
        "links": {"pages" : "/documents/1/pages"}
}
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21967780/77074) for a description of why adherence to Ember's expectations with regard to the JSON format is important and for an overview of the expected format.

Comment: Even with the ids without quotes and this "links" declaration "/documents/1/pages", the URL requested is : http://www.myserver.com/api/document/1/pages. When I remove this "links" declaration, I get the ID : http://www.myserver.com/api/pages/ID

Comment: I can't see the last bit of your comment but I'm assuming that you mean it still tries to retrieve `http://www.myserver.com/api/document/1/pages` and not `http://www.myserver.com/api/document/1/pages/1`

Comment: Yes. Ember Data is probably not for me ;)